# How to solve Flex utf-8 encoding

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, encoding, xmlsocket

I develop a facebook application using flex' s XMLSocket and Java.
When i type 'ş' character in my client side, it prints, however when i send 'ş' character,
it is printed as ??? or any kind of unpredictable characters.
I tried to change my html file's meta tag to 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
but it did not work.
On the whole how can i get rid of this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Where do you print your characters? In Flex app or somewhere else? If it's in a Flex/Flash app and you use embedded fonts make sure that those symbols are included in font. If it's on some other HTML page make sure that you read data as UTF char/string, not as basic char - UTF character can take up to 4 bytes. P.S.: Flash Player works only with UTF-8 so there's no need to specify encoding explicitly.

Comment: are you using the `Socket.writeUTF()/writeUTFBytes()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent(yourstring)`, this might do the trick.